# Iterating through nested dictionaries in Python

Tags: python

I'm really confused. This is from a book that I'm currently reading.

```
 allGuests = {'Alice': {'apples': 5, 'pretzels': 12},
'Bob': {'ham sandwiches': 3, 'apples': 2},
'Carol': {'cups': 3, 'apple pies': 1}}

def totalBrought(guests, item):
  numBrought = 0
  for k, v in guests.items():
    numBrought = numBrought + v.get(item, 0)
  return numBrought

print('Number of things being brought:')
print(' - Apples         ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'apples')))
print(' - Cups           ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'cups')))
print(' - Cakes          ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'cakes')))
print(' - Ham Sandwiches ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'ham sandwiches')))
print(' - Apple Pies     ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'apple pies')))
```

The book did a bad job explaining it (at least for me). I've been confused by this program because no explanation was really given.

The most confusing part for me is the:

```
def totalBrought(guests, item):
  numBrought = 0
  for k, v in guests.items():
    numBrought = numBrought + v.get(item, 0)
  return numBrought
```

This is the output:

```
Number of things being brought:
 - Apples         7
 - Cups           3
 - Cakes          0
 - Ham Sandwiches 3
 - Apple Pies     1
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what part of this program you don't understand. Frankly, it's a very basic program. I mean, it's only really 3 lines of code. What exactly are we supposed to explain here? Do you understand functions? Dictionaries? Loops? We can't explain *all* of that. You have to narrow the scope of this "explain, please" request by *a lot*.

Comment: k,v contain keys and values, is this what confused you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote9963 let me help you:

First I put some comments in the example code:

```
# In this code, we have a dictionary 'allGuests' that contains: 
#    "A guest (string) " and another dictionary 
#    (let call this dictionary as "bag" just for help ):

# So, we have:
# - Alice, another dictionary 
# - Bob, another dictionary
# - Carol, another dictionary

# Inside of Alice's bag we have: 'apples': 5, 'pretzels': 12
# Inside of Bob's bag we have: 'ham sandwiches': 3, 'apples': 2
# Inside of Carol's bag we have: 'cups': 3, 'apple pies': 1

# "bag"  is a "virtual name"to help you understand, but it is just another dictionary.    

allGuests = {'Alice': {'apples': 5, 'pretzels': 12},
'Bob': {'ham sandwiches': 3, 'apples': 2},
'Carol': {'cups': 3, 'apple pies': 1}}

# This method you pass the dictionary and the item that you are looking for.
def totalBrought(guests, item):
  numBrought = 0

  #'As a dictionary I can iterate in all elements of my dict using ".items()"'
  for k, v in guests.items():
    # I can get a element inside of my dictionary using ".get()"
    numBrought = numBrought + v.get(item, 0)
  return numBrought

print('\nNumber of things being brought:')
print(' - Apples         ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'apples')))
print(' - Cups           ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'cups')))
print(' - Cakes          ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'cakes')))
print(' - Ham Sandwiches ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'ham sandwiches')))
print(' - Apple Pies     ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'apple pies')))

print('\nMore information about python Dictionary object you can found here:')
print('https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp')
```

Let me get the first item that you are printing to try to make it easier:

```
print(' - Apples         ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'apples')))
```

We are invoking the 'method' `totalBrought` passing the dictionary `allGuests` and the item that you are looking for "`apples`."

Inside to method `totalBrought` we have the "`for k, v in guests.items()`"  this for iterate in our allGuests in each iteration **'k'** receive guest name and **'v'** the  dictionary that we put the nickname as 'bag'.

Finally, inside the loop, we get the item using '`v.get(item, 0)`' and incrementing the number of `numBrought`

Following `totalBrought` line by line passing `allGuests` and `apples`:

1. **numBrought** received **0**
2. Started `for k, v in guests.items():`
3. [for iteration 0] **K** received **Alice**
4. [for iteration 0] **V** received 'bag' with `{'apples': 5, 'pretzels': 12}`
5. [for iteration 0] `v.get(item, 0)` returned **5**
6. [for iteration 0] **numBrought** = 0 + 5
7. [for iteration 1] **K** received **Bob**
8. [for iteration 1] **V** received 'bag' with `{'ham sandwiches': 3, 'apples': 2},`
9. [for iteration 1] `v.get(item, 0)` returned **2**
10. [for iteration 1] **numBrought** = 5 + 2
11. [for iteration 2] **K** received **Carol**
12. [for iteration 2] **V** received 'bag' with `{'cups': 3, 'apple pies': 1}`
13. [for iteration 2] `v.get(item, 0)` returned **0**
14. [for iteration 2] **numBrought** = 7 + 0
15. Ended `for k, v in guests.items():`
16. return **numBrought**

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful answer! I felt stupid after you explained it to me. Only just started programming so I'm a bit overwhelmed

Comment: Don't worry, the first steps coding is hard, but if you keep going I'm pretty sure that you'll achieve your goals. Maybe this site https://www.hackerrank.com could help you with this journey.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the bulk of your confusion relates to python [dictionaries and key value pairs](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary).

The confusing part here is the fact that the `allGuests` dictionary is nested. This is to say that the value associated with every key element is in itself a dictionary. So, for example, looking up the Key `'Alice'` in the high level dictionary would return the dictionary `{'apples': 5, 'pretzels': 12}`. If you wanted to know how many apples Alice bought, you'd have to lookup the `'apple'` key in that nested dictionary (which would return 5). This is what the book was doing with `v.get(item, 0)`. The code you mentioned can be explained as so:

```
def totalBrought(guests, item):    #Remember, guests is a dictionary
  numBrought = 0                   #initialize the total number of items found to 0
  for k, v in guests.items():      #For Every Key (k) / Value (v) pair 
                                   #in the dictionary (iterating by keys)

    #Get the number of item objects bought. 
    #Note that v.get() is searching the nested dictionary by key value.
    numBrought = numBrought + v.get(item, 0) 
    return numBrought #Return the number of item objects in dictionary.
```